# find name of the execute file from withing the program

Tags: c

I am looking for a way to find the name of the executable file which runs it. meaning that if I have a file called `program` which runs something I would like to get its name.

Using `__FILE__` does not suite me since I need the executable name not the C files name which contains the code.

I am wondering if there is a gcc macro which can help me or a built in function which I couldn't find.

EDIT:
Also using `argv[0]` is not appropriate since I need to call the function not only inside main.

And passing the argv[0] parameter to all the functions that might need this parameter also isnt acceptable since it will be used in the entire system (I need to hash by it).

Comment: @zenith thnx. I was just adding it as a comment specifying it does not meet my needs.

Comment: Do you need this to work on Windows, or are POSIX systems sufficient?

Comment: I am running it on linux

Comment: But can't you pass `argv[0]` to whatever part of your code that needs it? Or just set `argv[0]` to a global variable or something if it's too much passing around?

Comment: If you say that you want the name of the executing program but that argv[0] is off the table, it sounds like you want something other than the name of the running program.  :)  Perhaps you could reword your question into the form of one that we can answer? :) :)

Comment: If you're a shared library, using argv is not terribly brilliant. You could use `readlink` on `"/proc/self/exe"`.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Its exactly the thing that I want, I have a big module which has many function calls inside the main function, inside the main there are only inits and all the implementation are inside other function, I dont want to pass the pointer across the entire system, rather I was looking for macro like __FILE__ that can give the executable name.

Comment: Macros are expanded at compile time, so if someone goes and changes the name of the executable after compilation, macros are out of question.

Comment: @zenith is exactly right.  The binary can always be renamed.  This is not something that can be determined at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    printf("%s",argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The first argument(`argv[0]`) contains the name of the program which is being run.

Comment: Hi and thanks, I am sorry but using argv[0] doesn't suite my needs, I was just adding it with edit when you answered.

Comment: @Anton.P copy `argv[0]`'s content and use it as you wish?

Comment: @Anton.P Please mark it as an edit with the `argv[0]`, otherwise people which comes here think that Cool Guy just completely misunderstood the question

Comment: @iharob thats a possibility but I dont want to pass the name as a parameter to every function that might use this feature. unfortunately that's too much functions.

Comment: @Anton.P Then use a global variable, but I would pass the variable.

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition for `main()` in C is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

`argv[0]` contains the name of the program as executed.

Comment: Hi and thanks, I am sorry but using argv[0] doesn't suite my needs, I was just adding it with edit when you answered.

Comment: OP has mentioned against `argv[0]`.

Comment: That's a really weird requirement.  Is this code golf?

Comment: Anton, you can define global pointer, like `char * exeName;` and in the main function assigne it like `exeName = argv [0];`. So, this global string will be available for any function in your code.

Answer (score 2):

From `main`, pass `argv[0]` to wherever you might need the program's name.

Or if a lot of functions need it and you want to avoid passing it around too much, assign it to a global variable.

You asked for macros as a solution, but they are expanded at compile time. And since the name of the executable file can be changed after compilation, what you want cannot be determined at compile time, so macros are out of question.

Comment: There program is quite large and contains dozens of such modules, the feature I am adding is a small one and I dont want to make changes in all the modules just to add a tiny feature.

Comment: @Anton.P The only solution I can see is to add two lines to define a global variable and in `main` assign `argv[0]` to that. Would two small lines be too much modification?

Comment: That doesn't seem to me like you have to make changes to all modules.

Answer (score 1):

Often remembering `argv[0]` from `main` will be quite sufficient.

If this is not the case -- for example if you're a shared library, or if you worry that your caller started you with a faked `argv[0]` (this is possible but unusual), you can, on POSIX-compliant systems with a mounted `/proc`, use [`readlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) to resolve `/proc/self/exe` and get a path to the main binary of the running process:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Note that readlink does not null-terminate the result itself. This
// is important if the link target contains null bytes itself, I suppose,
// but it means that you have to take care that the null-terminator is
// placed yourself if you're going to use the file name as a string.
char buf[PATH_MAX] = { 0 };
readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, PATH_MAX);
```

And on Windows, there is the [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) function:

```
#include <windows.h>

TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buf, MAX_PATH);
```

Answer (score 0):

The startup name is given via `main()`'s `argv[0]` and can be considered constant.

So why not make it available through out the program using a global reference to it.

progname.h

```
#ifndef PROGNAME_H
#define PROGNAME_H

extern char * progname;

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "progname.h"

char * progname = NULL;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  progname = argv[0];

  ...

}
```

Access it from any where like so

module1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "progname.h"

void f(void)
{
  printf("progname='%s'\n", progname ?progname :"<not set>");
}
```